# transform.SetParent vs TransformPoint(InverseTransformPoint())

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If an object often needs (change could occur nearly each frame) to follow another object than it's parent, can I use `transform.SetParent()` everytime or is it better to stay in the parent and use `transform.TransformPoint(otherObject.InverseTransformPoint(localPosInOtherObject))` ?

Comment: This is really up to you to answer. If you use SetParent, the parent Object controls the not just the position but the rotation and the scale of the other object too. Do you want that? If that doesn't matter to you then it shouldn't matter which one you use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the main keyword : performance ! :) I was wondering if one of these methods had more overhead or something. For example triggering recalculations about the list of children

Comment: Why not try it yourself. Use the Profiler to see if that happens with any  of them